# Card layout parameters not working

Tags: java, android, xml

I am trying to implement a list of Card views, and the list is fine, but the layout inside the card is nothing like what i have defined in the XML. Any ideas why this is not showing properly? Here is my card XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/cvAdvertFavourite"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dip"
    android:layout_marginBottom="2dip"
    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="8dp"
        >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivCardFavouriteAnimalPhoto"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvCardFavouriteTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ivCardFavouriteAnimalPhoto"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvCardFavouriteRace"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tvCardFavouriteTitle"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ivCardFavouriteAnimalPhoto"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvCardFavouritePrice"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tvCardFavouriteRace"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ivCardFavouriteAnimalPhoto"
            />

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

I use this RecyclerView XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="16dp"
    >

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView

        android:id="@+id/rvCardFavourite"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is my CardItem class:

```
public class FavouriteCardItem {

    Bitmap animal;
    int price;
    String title, race;

    public FavouriteCardItem(Bitmap animal, int price, String title, String race){
        this.animal = animal;
        this.price = price;
        this.title = title;
        this.race = race;
    }

    public Bitmap getAnimal() {
        return animal;
    }

    public void setAnimal(Bitmap animal) {
        this.animal = animal;
    }

    public int getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(int price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getRace() {
        return race;
    }

    public void setRace(String race) {
        this.race = race;
    }
}
```

Here is how I call my adapter and set the data for the adapter:

```
private void loadSetData() {
        List<FavouriteCardItem> items = new ArrayList<FavouriteCardItem>();
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getActivity().getResources(),
                R.drawable.bird);
        FavouriteCardItem item1 = new FavouriteCardItem(bitmap, 100, "birds", "birds");
        items.add(item1);
        Bitmap bitmap2 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getActivity().getResources(),
                R.drawable.dog);
        FavouriteCardItem item2 = new FavouriteCardItem(bitmap2, 200, "dogs", "dogs");
        items.add(item2);
        Bitmap bitmap3 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getActivity().getResources(),
                R.drawable.cat);
        FavouriteCardItem item3 = new FavouriteCardItem(bitmap3, 1000, "cats", "cats");
        items.add(item3);

        FavouriteCardAdapter adapter = new FavouriteCardAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.card_view, items);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

And this is my Adapter class:

```
public class FavouriteCardAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<FavouriteCardAdapter.CardViewHolder> {

    private Context mContext;
    private int resourceId;
    List<FavouriteCardItem> cardItems;

    public FavouriteCardAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<FavouriteCardItem> cardItems){
        mContext = context;
        resourceId = resource;
        this.cardItems = cardItems;
    }


    @Override
    public CardViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_view, parent, false);
        CardViewHolder cvh = new CardViewHolder(v);
        return cvh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(CardViewHolder holder, int position) {
        DisplayMetrics metrics = Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics();
        int screenHeight = metrics.heightPixels;

        holder.cardView.getLayoutParams().height = screenHeight / 4;
        int price = cardItems.get(position).getPrice();
        String price1 = Integer.toString(price);
        holder.tvPrice.setText(price1);
        holder.tvRace.setText(cardItems.get(position).getRace());
        holder.tvTitle.setText(cardItems.get(position).getTitle());
        holder.ivAnimal.setImageBitmap(cardItems.get(position).getAnimal());
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return cardItems.size();
    }

    public class CardViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        CardView cardView;
        ImageView ivAnimal;
        TextView tvPrice, tvTitle, tvRace;

        public CardViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            cardView = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cvAdvertFavourite);
            ivAnimal = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivCardFavouriteAnimalPhoto);
            tvPrice = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvCardFavouritePrice);
            tvTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvCardFavouriteTitle);
            tvRace = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvCardFavouriteRace);
        }
    }
}
```

BTW I am aware that I am not supposed to load images like this and so on, but I just wanted to create some test data to get the layout right before i start loading the data from the online data storage.

Here is how the whole Card view looks like. It should have 3 textViews and 1 imageView, but it only shows one imageView.....

[image]

Comment: change width and height of imageview (ivCardFavouriteAnimalPhoto) to 150dp from wrap content...then you will understand while only imageview is only visible

Comment: because 150dp is supporting multiple screen sizes?

Comment: my point is image view is consuming most of the space hence no space left for textview....Infact even if you remove the padding of 8dp in Relative layout then image will the touch the card boundary...you can check it.

Comment: I get your point. So i should also set the image size programatically, to make sure it only takes up a third of the card width, just as an example?

Comment: try with the answer I have posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can try this as one of the solution if you do not want to specify the dimension for width and height of Image**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/cvAdvertFavourite"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dip"
    android:layout_marginBottom="2dip"
    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="8dp"
        >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivCardFavouriteAnimalPhoto"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:weight = "2"/>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:weight = "1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvCardFavouriteTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvCardFavouriteRace"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tvCardFavouriteTitle"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvCardFavouritePrice"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tvCardFavouriteRace"
            />
      </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

In this I have used LinearLayout which will distribute the screen width in the ratio 2:1 between ImageView and RelativeLayout with text.

 Also I have reduced the size of text from 30sp to 20sp

Answer (score 0):

try to make your card xml look like this:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
android:id="@+id/cvAdvertFavourite"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginTop="2dip"
android:layout_marginBottom="2dip"
card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
>
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/something"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivCardFavouriteAnimalPhoto"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/your_size_of_image" // the important part
            android:layout_height="@dimen/your_size_of_image" // the important part
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

        <LinearLayout // make sure you are using a linearlyout 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/ivCardFavouriteAnimalPhoto"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/ivCardFavouriteAnimalPhoto"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvCardFavouriteTitle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal" />

             <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvCardFavouriteRace"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal" />

              <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvCardFavouritePrice"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```